# MUI Datagrid single select activation on one click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I’m having to double click on a cell to show the dropdown of options on the single select-able column in an MUI Datagrid.

Can I have the dropdown come up with just one click? Is there a hacky way around by having the cells be in focus most of the time?

Comment: Refer this example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/material-demo-forked-c0ldcq?file=%2Fdemo.tsx%3A52%2C14